# Is there an easy way to make a min heap in C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, heap, min

I'm very new to C++, and I was wondering if there was a way to make a min heap in C++ from the standard library.

Comment: You ask questions and accept none. Is this behavior by habit or choice?

Answer (score 54):

Use `make_heap()` and friends, defined in `<algorithm>`, or use `priority_queue`, defined in `<queue>`. The `priority_queue` uses `make_heap` and friends underneath.

```
#include <queue> // functional,iostream,ctime,cstdlib
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    srand(time(0));
    priority_queue<int,vector<int>,greater<int> > q;
    for( int i = 0; i != 10; ++i ) q.push(rand()%10);
    cout << "Min-heap, popped one by one: ";
    while( ! q.empty() ) {
        cout << q.top() << ' ';  // 0 3 3 3 4 5 5 6 8 9
        q.pop();
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::make_heap`, `std::push_heap`, and others directly, or you can use a `std::priority_queue` built on a `std::vector` or similar.

The `std::*_heap` methods are in `<algorithm>`, and the `std::priority_queue` template is in `<queue>`.

Comment: oh so if i popped from the priority_queue in c++ i'd get the min value?

Comment: To clarify further, `priority_queue`'s whole template accepts a container type, which defaults to `vector<T>`.  Any container which supports random iteration and `push_back` will suffice, however.

Comment: If say I have priority_queue<Node>, how do I set the sorting function of the queue?

Comment: You would use the full template; in paraphrase, `priority_queue<T, container, comp>`.

This question, and your original, honestly, is something you should be able to google yourself and find a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @Alex: Or simply declare `Node::operator<`.

Comment: To clarify more, `priority_queue` is a **max**-heap, if you want a min-heap, you have to use `std::greater` as a comparator. See Wilhelm's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [std::priority_queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) defined in  with [std::greater](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) defined in .

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int>> minHeap();
minHeap.push(5);
minHeap.push(1);
minHeap.push(3);
minHeap.push(2);
minHeap.push(4);

while (!minHeap.empty()){
   std::cout << minHeap.top() << std::endl;
   minHeap.pop();
}
```

This will print:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```