# Loop that creates doubles and insert them into sorted array, in C

Tags: c, sorting

Suppose I have a set of sorted doubles.

```
{ 0.124, 4.567, 12.3 }
```

A positive, non-zero double is created by another part of the code, and needs to be inserted into this set while keeping it sorted. For example, if the created double is `7.56`, the final result is,

```
{ 0.124, 4.567, 7.56, 12.3 }
```

In my code, this "create double and insert in sorted set" process is then repeated a great number of times. Possibly 500k to 1 million times. I don't know how many doubles will be created in total exactly, but I know the upper bound.

**Attempt**

My naive first approach was to create an array with length = upper bound and fill it with zeros, then adding the initial set of doubles to it ("add" = replace a 0 valued entry with the double). Whenever a double is created, I add it to the array and do an insertion sort, which I read is good for sorting ordered arrays.

**Question**

I have a feeling running 500k to 1 million insertion slots will be a serious performance issue. (or am I wrong?) Is there a more efficient data structure and/or algorithm for doing this in C?

**Edit:**

The reason why I want to keep the set sorted is because after every "create double and insert in sorted set" process, I need to be able to look up the smallest element in that set (and possibly remove it by replacing it with a 0). I thought the best way to do this would be to keep the set sorted.

But if that is not the case, perhaps there is an alternative?

Comment: Perhaps a skip list would help if you're going to have 1M entries.

Comment: Does it have to be a sorted list? This problem is much more amenable to a balanced binary search tree (or similar ordered tree).

Comment: @nneonneo - I need to be able to pick the smallest double in the set after every "create and insert" process. I thought the best way would be to keep this set sorted (will edit to reflect this). Can I use a balanced binary search tree in this case?

Comment: If you only ever need the *smallest* double, use a min-heap. That's O(log n) insertion and O(1) min-query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since all you want to do is pull out the minimum element in every iteration, use a [min-heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) instead. You can implement them to have O(1) *insertion*, O(1) *find-min*, and O(1) *decrease-key* operations (though note that removing the minimum element always takes O(log n) time). For what you are doing, a heap will be substantially faster.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like this might be the solution. Was about to ask you to write that comment up as an answer. Will look up min-heap (I'm not familiar with it), and accept if it works out. I don't suppose you know of a good guide or tutorial (or even library) for min-heap in C?

Comment: There's min-heaps in the C++ STL (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786398/is-there-an-easy-way-to-make-a-min-heap-in-c), but I don't know any implementations in C OTOH. But, binary heaps are very easy to implement once you get the idea, and can be implemented on top of an array very easily (<50 lines of code).

Comment: I should note that a binary heap is a bit slower if you don't remove the minimum element frequently. But, in any case, O(n log n) is much, much better than O(n^2).

Comment: Noted. I intend to remove the minimum element every time I "find-min". Will do some reading up to get a better picture, then will +1 and accept your answer. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Rather than running an insertion sort, you could use binary search to find the insertion point, and then insert the value there. But this is slow, because you may need to shift a lot of data many times (think what happens if the random data comes in sorted in reverse of what you need, the timing would be `O(N^2)`).

The fastest approach is to insert first, and then sort everything at once. If this is not possible, consider replacing your array with a self-balancing ordered tree structure, such as an [RB-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree).

Comment: Or even a B-tree, with fixed size arrays in the leaves.

Comment: Using binary search is not asymptotically any faster (and actually might be a bit slower, since you can normally perform the array move as you look for the element). An ordered tree structure would be ideal for this task, methinks. (Or, just a huge array that is sorted post-hoc...)

Comment: @nneonneo That's pretty much the essence of the second paragraph.

Comment: Actually, why would the running time be O(n^2 logn)? It's only O(n^2). The running time of each loop is dominated by the array move, not the binary search.

Comment: @nneonneo Yes, you're right, each nested iteration is `O(N+LogN)`, not `O(N*LogN)`. Thanks!