# Implementing Min Heap in C - using array?

Tags: c, binary-tree, min-heap

I am trying to learn and implement a min-heap to solve a problem: [Loop that creates doubles and insert them into sorted array, in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606895/loop-that-creates-doubles-and-insert-them-into-sorted-array-in-c)

Basically, I start with a set of doubles, sorted from smallest to largest. Then, I generate doubles (possibly at random) and have to add the newly generated doubles to the set while keeping it sorted. Also, each time I insert a double, I remove the smallest double from the set.

(**edit** - The set doesn't have to be entirely sorted. The goal is to be able to look up and remove the minimum element after every insertion of a double. Keeping the set sorted was my first, naive, solution.)

Sounds like the kind of thing a min-heap was made to do.

**Attempt**

Since in C, array sizes are declared in advance, I have to create an array with length = maximum number of doubles I will end up with. Then, fill all the entries of this array with the value max_double.

Using the methods described here as a guide: http://opendatastructures.org/versions/edition-0.1e/ods-java/10_1_BinaryHeap_Implicit_Bi.html, I can make functions to insert and remove values into this array.

Insert: Replace the last entry (which will always be max_double) of the array with the number. Then keep swapping with the value of the parent node until the parent node's value is less than newly added value.

Remove: Replace the root node with max_double, and then compare it with its two children, swapping with the least of the children until its two children are max_double.

**Question**

Am I using the right approach for all these?

Comment: "Since in C, array sizes are declared in advance", except if you know about the `malloc()` function (of which you should not cast the return value).

Comment: @H2CO3 haha :) I suggest use realloc() in this case...

Comment: @H2CO3 - I am new to C (coming from Python). Should I be learning malloc() and building this as a dynamic array?

Comment: @Legendre yes, most probably :)

Comment: @aTo oh, you and `malloc()`, we meet again... :D

Comment: @H2CO3 Hello my friend we meet again! :) Similar discussion eh~ :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A heap will not make the array sorted. It simply follows the rules, meaning that in a min heap, the parent will always be smaller then his children. Unfortunately, the children do not have to be in order.

If you want to implement a heap in an array, the wiki has a great page about it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap

Some more explanation:

Insert : 
Add the element to the end of the array (no replacing!)
Compare the element with the parent at(i-1/2) if the order is correct stop.
Otherwise swap and do step 2 again. (remember to update the current index)

Delete : 
Swap min with last element in the array
Delete the last element
Now going from the top, compare the root with its children, swap with the smallest, otherwise stop.
Keep comparing with the children until the condition is satisfied or you don't have any other children.

For index starting at 0, the parent is at floor((i-1)/2) and children are at 2i+1 and 2i+2

One more thing, i suggest using a deque to store your doubles.

Comment: besides, if the sets are not big enough then it sound like an awful lot of work to do (he's trying to build a tree)

Comment: The reason why I want to sort the double is to be able to pick the smallest from the set (so it doesn't matter if the set is entirely sorted) Sorry, should have made this clear. Also, that wiki article was quite confusing to me. I think this guide (for Java unfortunately) does it much better: http://opendatastructures.org/versions/edition-0.1e/ods-java/10_1_BinaryHeap_Implicit_Bi.html

Comment: @Legendre: A min heap allows you to always pick off the smallest item from a set *without keeping everything in sorted order*.  That's what a min heap is *for* :)

Comment: @j_random_hacker - Yep, thats why I decided to use a min heap instead of sorting again and again like I did before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606895/loop-that-creates-doubles-and-insert-them-into-sorted-array-in-c