# ios - Is there any heap implementation?

Tags: ios

I'm looking for a min heap implementation in ios.
I've been searching for one for a while but couldn't find any such solution.
Does such a data structure exit in ios? If not, does anyone know of an open source alternative?

Thank you

Comment: Look at the duplicate question. There are lots of alternatives too.

Comment: and see wilhelmtell's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786398/is-there-an-easy-way-to-make-a-min-heap-in-c