# Rearrange Fifo Queue based on Variable

Tags: c++, queue, fifo

I have this Queue below which is FIFO.

queue Printers[1];

I have the following information stored on each front in a queue.

```
int PID;
string Filename;
int Memstart;
char rw;
int Filelength;
int Cylinder;
```

If I was to add to this queue it would just pop it on every time and wouldnt be ordered.

Is there a hack or a way to rearrange this queue based on the Cylinder?

I want it so that the queue is based in order on the Cylinder.

So for example if I add to the queue

Cylinder 1 3 6 3 in that order, it would come out in the order 1 3 3 6.

Is there a way to rearrange a fifo queue based on a certain variable?

Thanks!

Comment: And not just for printing, i want to rearrange this queue. perhaps there is a way to print it into an array? how would this work?

Answer (score 1):

Well a fifo queue is by definition First-In-First-Out, so that's not going to give you what you want, you may want look into something like a Priority Queue (also called Min Heap)

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29)

Comment: And can you arrange it based on a variable such as Cylinder in a class?

Comment: Yes you can define what is the 'key' that you want to use for order. Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786398/is-there-an-easy-way-to-make-a-min-heap-in-c

Comment: Is there a way to mimic creating multiple queues like this but with priority queue?

This is what i have but i want to now use a priority queue.

    `queue<PCB> Disks[DiskDevices];`

I tried this but it doesnt work.

    `priority_queue<PCB> DisksTest[DiskDevices];`

It wont compile? What am i doing wrong?